# How to make my app persistence

Tags: android, persistence

I'm a new with Android. I want to make an application that always running. User can't switch to other application, if my app is exited then it will be launched automatically.

Comment: Android is designed to **not** allow this. **Every** app can be exited. What you're trying to do is counter to the design of the system, so it will be very hard if not impossible.

Comment: first mention clear that exactly what you have trying to do and why? then after anybody like to give suggestion.

Comment: Hi, I want to make my Android application always running, what could i do to make it always running on screen. The device is only for running this application not for other app.

Comment: Not virus. Can you show some idea about that.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with intent filters in your manifest, on your activity.

```
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

This makes your activity an alternative for the home-app, but the user needs to select your app as the default app the first time it's run. There is no other way.

After the user selects your app as the default home app it will be launched every time 'home' is pressed. You can then capture the other buttons as usual and do whatever you want (e.g. nothing when 'back' is pressed).

Answer (score 0):

into AndsroidManifest insert this:
`<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />`